How to Conditionally Display a Component Using combineLatest in RxJS Without Null Errors?
I want to display a component in my template only if both of my observables do not emit null or undefined.
I use the combineLatest operator from RxJS to simplify the conditional rendering. However, I still encounter an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username').
Why is my component initialized with null variables while the combineLatest operator emits true after it has checked for non-null values?
I tried a nested ngIf solution as suggested here: ngIf with multiple async pipe variables, which works, but I want to simplify it using combineLatest : *ngIf with multiple async pipe variables
Here is my current implementation:
In parent component:
this.cardAd$ = this._cardAdService.getCardAd(this.id);
this.cardOwner$ = this.cardAd$.pipe(
    switchMap((cardAd: CardAdInfo) => this._userService.getUserInfo(cardAd.userCard.userId))
);

this.isInfoBarVisible$ = combineLatest([this.cardAd$, this.cardOwner$]).pipe(
    map(([cardAd, cardOwner]) => !!cardAd && !!cardOwner)
);


        <app-offer-create-info-bar
            *ngIf="isInfoBarVisible$ | async"
            [cardAd]="(cardAd$ | async)!"
            [cardOwner]="(cardOwner$ | async)!">
        </app-offer-create-info-bar>

Child component:
<div>
     {{ cardOwner.username }}{{ cardAd.name }} 
</div>


export class OfferCreateInfoBarComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input({ required: true }) cardAd!: CardAdInfo;
    @Input({ required: true }) cardOwner!: UserInfo;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('cardAd', this.cardAd); // null
        console.log('cardOwner', this.cardOwner); // null
    }
}


add shareReplay(1) to both of streams whose results should be reused. this way  the downloaded value would be passed to the component, and not downloaded again
this.cardAd$ = this._cardAdService.getCardAd(this.id).pipe(shareReplay(1));
this.cardOwner$ = this.cardAd$.pipe(
    switchMap((cardAd: CardAdInfo) => this._userService.getUserInfo(cardAd.userCard.userId)),
    shareReplay(1),
);

